# Micropython POST request body empty

Tags: json, rest, sockets, post, micropython

i have a server with POST e REST services. Using micropython i need to perform POST request.
GET queries arrive at the REST services and respond correctly using the following format:

```
s.send(b"GET /sensordata/premises HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:XX.XXX.XXX.XXX\r\n" + "Accept: application/json\r\n\r\n")
```

but for the POST looks like the request arrived to server, but the body is empty. For some reason the JSON body of the request is not interpreted in a correct way.

```
 from network import WLAN
import socket
import machine
import time
import struct
import json
import pycom

wlan = WLAN(mode=WLAN.STA)
wlan.connect("*****", auth=(WLAN.WPA2, "*****"), timeout=5000)

while not wlan.isconnected():
    machine.idle()
print("Connected to WiFi\n")

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
url = 'XX.XXX.XXX.XXX'

sockaddr = socket.getaddrinfo(url, 80) [0][-1]
s.connect(sockaddr)

print('socket connected')

httpreq = b'POST /sensordata/insertrecords HTTP/1.1 \r\n Host:XX.XXX.XXX.XXX \r\n' + 'Accept: application/json \r\n' + 'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' + ' {\"node_id\":\"1\",\"value\":[{\"measure_time_stamp\":\"2020-10-06T09:25:43\",\"temp\":\"14\",\"humidity\":\"75\",\"ph1\":11,\"ph2\":12,\"ph3\":13}]}\r\n\r\n'
s.send(httpreq)
time.sleep(1)
rec_bytes = s.recv(4096)
print("RESPONSE = " + str(rec_bytes))
print('end')
s.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the [urequests](https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/tree/master/python-ecosys/urequests) library? It's an HTTP client library inspired by the popular Python [requests](https://github.com/psf/requests). A POST request is simply:

```
import urequests
r = urequests.post('https://your/endpoint')
```